# EXCEL formula - Runtime Error 28

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have a VBA that works - but leads to a **Run Time Error 28** after a while.
Colum B3:B11 have **Hide** or **Show** from a function in them
**=IF(E3=0,"Hide","Show")**  E3:E11 has a dollar amount or 0 from another sheet.
Here is the VBA

```
Sub hidelines()
If Range("B3").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("3:3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B3").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("3:3").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
If Range("B4").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B4").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
If Range("B5").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
If Range("B6").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B6").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("6:6").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
If Range("B7").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("7:7").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B7").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("7:7").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
If Range("B8").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("8:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B8").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("8:8").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
If Range("B9").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("9:9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B9").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("9:9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
If Range("B10").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B10").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
If Range("B11").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B11").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to auto call **hidelines** when any of the E3:E11 have a dollar amount or 0

I appreciate any assistance - I am stumped...   Thanks, Ed...

Comment: VBA **hidelines** it:

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
hidelines
End Sub

Comment: Your code is working fine (hidelines), instead of calling it in sheetcalculation please try calling it in Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Comment: Hi Linga - Thank you for getting back to me.
I am no longer getting the Run Time Error 28
**but**,  it does not **automatically run** when the field is changed by the formula or even if I manually type   **Hide**

Comment: @Linga  
 
Hi Linga - I am no longer getting the Run Time Error 28 *Thanks* -  **but**, it does not **automatically run** when the field is changed by the formula or even if I manually type **Hide**

Comment: Glad to know that :)